# Scala - convert list of arrays to key:values

Tags: arrays, list, scala

I Have a list of arrays:
List(Array(a,1), Array(a,2), Array(a,3), Array(b,1), Array(b,2))

i want to end up with something, i'm not sure if it's supposed to be a list or not, but will look like:

((a),(1,2,3)),((b),(1,2))

Comment: Is there any reason by you have that array structure in the first place? It's very awkward to work with.

Comment: no it doesn't have to be Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to have a better idea as to what types, exactly, you're looking to have. Your question seems to suggest that you're expecting tuples of varying lengths which is, undoubtedly, a very un-useful form.

Here is an example that provides you with a Map[Any, List[Any]]:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = List(Array("a",1), Array("a",2), Array("a",3), Array("b",1), Array("b",2))
    val r = x.groupBy(_.head).mapValues(_.flatMap(_.tail))

    println(r)
  }
}

// Output
// Map(b -> List(1, 2), a -> List(1, 2, 3))
```